# Fullscreen responsive panoramic image

Tags: jquery, fullscreen

i have a panoramic image 6400 pixels width x 1080 pixels height.

I've been trying different scripts based of Jquery, but i couldn't customize them for my purposes.

I'd like the image to be displayed at 100% height of the screen size, rescaling when the size of window is changed, but at the same time, leaving the horizontal scale intact, with a scrollbar at bottom to move along the entire size of the image horizontally.

Is there any way to do this?…

I couldn't find in any website or forum.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried to put your image in a div. width and height 100%, and set the height of the div at 100% with a overflow:scroll ?

Comment: visibly, you can change the image ratio by playing with background-size  http://jsfiddle.net/vyfjV/1/

Comment: Instead of scanning websites and forums for ready-made solutions, why not try to apply some creative thinking and imagination and have a go at it yourself? At the very least, in the attempt you will discover which techniques and components you need to get the job done, and you should be able to find information about _those_ on the internet. You're just applying too broad reasoning right now.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you want, you shouldn't really need a script for that.
[This very basic example](http://jsbin.com/aGIteci/1) should work with any modern browser and could be a good start.
It uses only one `<img>` element and the following CSS:

```
html, body, img {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100%;
  display: block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If it doesn't need to use jQuery, you could have a look a at using three.js to get a nice [panoramic effect](http://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_panorama_equirectangular). The example I linked could easily be adapted to include a scrollbar that just rotates the camera around, although clicking and dragging on the image a much nicer form of interaction than dragging a scrollbar. You could also limit the camera rotation if your panorama image is not 360x180.